# LINQ - Find "path" along Legs

Tags: c#, linq

Suppose I have simple "leg" Class defined by two points (actually PointIDs):

```
public class Leg
{
    public int p1Id;
    public int p2Id;
}
```

List of Legs are "interconnected", on the way that pt2 of one leg is same as pt1 of another leg (except first and last one). Let's initialize simple list:

```
var legs = new List<Leg>();

var l1 = new Leg { p1Id = 1, p2Id = 2 };
var l2 = new Leg { p1Id = 4, p2Id = 5 };
var l3 = new Leg { p1Id = 2, p2Id = 3 };
var l4 = new Leg { p1Id = 5, p2Id = 6 };
var l5 = new Leg { p1Id = 3, p2Id = 4 };

legs.Add(l1);
legs.Add(l2);
legs.Add(l3);
legs.Add(l4);
legs.Add(l5);
```

Fact is that this list of legs is not sorted, and of course IDs are not consecutive, like it is the case in this example.

Question is how to create function which will return list of consecutive points, between two given points, so:

```
var myLegs = FindMyLegs(legs, 5, 2);
```

.. should return following list : 5, 4, 3, 2

I guess it might be done by LINQ and inner join list of legs twice (legs1.pt2Id == legs2.pt1Id), but I am really not experienced in LINQ, and I can not find right way.

Basically I'll need some function:

```
List<int> FindMyLegs(List<Leg> allLegs, int startPt, int endPt) { ??? }
```

Comment: `FindMyLegs` facepalm.

Comment: This would be easier with bunch of loops than trying to hack it with LINQ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, then I don't think that Linq will be the whole solution here. I think you'll need to build up a data structure that's suited to this kind of problem, and then choose appropriate algorithms to find your paths.

Take a look at [Dijkstra's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) as a starting point.

Comment: Sure, LINQ is really not requirement here, but I thought that at least I could connect and in the same time sort leg segments by LINQ, on a quite elegant way. I can't change database data (where these legs are stored), so this is what I have. I am familiar with Dijkstra, but actually I don't have to find "shortest" path or something like that, I just need to have list of connected segments from A to B.

Comment: Like I said. I don't expect Linq to be the whole solution here, but it may help you get the data in shape. I can't picture any query that will help you a lot here though. Cheers for the down vote :) I'll leave you to it then...

Comment: it seems I incidentally push down arrow, really sorry for that, just put it back, thanks for help....

Answer (score 1):

I hope this is what you need

```
    private List<int> FindMyLegs(List<Leg> allLegs, int startPt, int endPt)
    {
        return allLegs.Where(l => l.p1Id <= startPt && l.p1Id >=endPt).Select(l => l.p1Id).OrderByDescending(x => x).ToList();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope it could help you:

```
    public static List<int> FindMyLegs(List<Leg> allLegs, int startPt, int endPt)
    {
        var result = new List<int>();

        var pre_result = allLegs.Where(l => (l.p1Id >= startPt && l.p2Id <= endPt) || (l.p2Id <= startPt && l.p1Id >= endPt));
        foreach (var leg in pre_result)
        {
            result.Add(leg.p1Id);
            result.Add(leg.p2Id);
        }

        result = (startPt > endPt ? result.OrderBy(t => t) : result.OrderByDescending(t => t)).Distinct().ToList();

        return result;
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        var legs = new List<Leg>();

        var l1 = new Leg { p1Id = 1, p2Id = 2 };
        var l2 = new Leg { p1Id = 4, p2Id = 5 };
        var l3 = new Leg { p1Id = 2, p2Id = 3 };
        var l4 = new Leg { p1Id = 5, p2Id = 6 };
        var l5 = new Leg { p1Id = 3, p2Id = 4 };

        legs.Add(l1);
        legs.Add(l2);
        legs.Add(l3);
        legs.Add(l4);
        legs.Add(l5);

        var myLegs = FindMyLegs(legs, 2, 5);

        foreach (var leg in myLegs)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(leg);
        }
    }
```

Result:

```
var myLegs = FindMyLegs(legs, 2, 5);
```

5
4
3
2

```
var myLegs = FindMyLegs(legs, 4, 1);
```

1
2
3
4

Comment: Thanks for the code FSou1 and Sriram.
Unfortunatelly, IDs are not ordered, I've just put them sorted, to easier understand needed result. In my case IDs are completely random, and all I know is that leg starts, where another leg ends (by comparing PointIDs). So my result should likely be:

458893, 328874, 909983, 118782, 338877, etc...

Thanks for help, anyway...